# How to fetch Districts Of A State using MysQL

Tags: php, mysql

My Code:

```
<?php           
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','password','dbname');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$state = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['state']);
$bank = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['bank']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE state='$state' AND bankName='$bank'";   
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);      
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                    
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
$bank = $row['bankName'];
$district = $row['district'];
$state = $row['state'];
}
}
?>
```

The above code is working fine using get value and to echo bank name and state name.
I've been trying to run another mysql query in to fetch all district lists of a selected state of a particular bank, For example, there is a bank called ABC having multiple branches in a state called Delhi where Delhi is divided into 8 districts. So I'd like fetch all 8 districts list of Delhi of ABC bank. 
To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT distinct bankName, state, district FROM table where bankName='$bank' group by state and district";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);          
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
<section class="left">
<h1>District-wise list of <?php echo $bank; ?> Branches in <?php echo $state; ?></h1>
<p>Branches of <?php echo $bank; ?> are available at <?php echo $rowcount; ?> <?php echo $districts; ?> districts of <?php echo $state; ?> in India</p>
<?php 

echo "<ul class=\"states\">\n";         
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                    
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                              
echo "<li><a href='/bank/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['bankName'])."/state/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['state'])."/district/".str_replace($remove, "-", $row['district'])."'>" . $row["district"]. "</a></li>\n";  
}
echo "</ul>";
} else {
echo "<p>No results Found</p>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</section>
```

This returns no results found. Please help me with this query.

Thanks

Vikas

Comment: You should add error handling to your code when issuing sql statements to see if anything goes wrong. Your code simply assumes that everything is always fine with the mysql part.

Comment: If you run the SQL query in phpMyAdmin (or similar), does it give you any result? Any errors?

Comment: Hi, Tried it but it is returning all districts of all states instead of Delhi being the single selected through get value :(

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you expect:

```
SELECT distinct bankName, state, district
FROM table
where bankName = '$bank'
group by state and district
---------------^
```

In many databases, this would result in an error, because `state` and `district` are not boolean expressions.  This is allowed in MySQL.  Basically, it returns either true or false, depending on whether the strings look like a "true" value or "false" value to MySQL.  (I think MySQL will convert them to numbers and compare them to 0, so if the values start with letters the result will always be false; but that is unimportant.)

You intend a comma:

```
SELECT distinct bankName, state, district
FROM table
where bankName = '$bank'
group by state, district;
```

But, you don't need the `GROUP BY` at all with the `DISTINCT`.  So, get rid of one or the other:

```
SELECT distinct bankName, state, district
FROM table
where bankName = '$bank';
```

Also, you should get in the habit of using parameterized queries rather than embedding values in the query string.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it returned all state's districts wherever the bank branches are available :(

Comment: @VikasKukreja . . . That appears to be the intention of your query.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed it using:
`$sql="SELECT`bankName`,`state`,`district`, count(`district`) as totcount FROM`ifsccodes`WHERE bankName='$bank' AND`state`LIKE '%$state%'  group by`district`";'

Thanks everyone for your help :)